# register and memory, risc-v

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, riscv

I'm studying computer architecture in my university and I guess I don't know the basic of computer system and C language concepts, few things really confuse me and I was kept searching bout it but couldn't find answer what I want and make me more confuse so upload question here.

1. I thought register is holding an instruction, storage address or any kind of data in CPU. And I also learned memory layout.

------------------

stack

dynamic data

static data

text

reserved part

------------------

Then register is having this memory layout in CPU? Or am I just confusing it with computer's 5 components(input, output, memory, control, datapath)'s memory's layout. I thought this is one of this 5 component's layout.

RISC-V (while loop in C)

```
Loop:
   slli x10, x22, 3
   add x10, x10, x25
   ld x9, 0(x10)
   bne x9, x24, Exit
   addi x22, x22, 1
   beq x0, x0, Loop
Exit:...
```

Then where does this operation happens? Register?

2. I learned RISC-V Registers like below.

- x0: the constant value 0
- x1: return address
- ...
- x5-x7, x28-x31: temporaries
- ...

If register is in that memory layout what I draw above, then that x0, x1 stuffs are contained in where? It doesn't make sense from here. So I'm confusing how do I have to think register looks like.

Everything is so abstract in my mind so I guess question sounds bit weird. If anything is not cleared, comment me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then register is having this memory layout in CPU?

No, that makes zero sense, your thinking is on the wrong track here.

The register file is its own separate space, not part of memory address space.  It's not indexable with a variable, only by hard-coding register numbers into instructions, so there's not really any sense in which `x2` is the "next register after `x1`" or anything.  e.g. you can't loop over registers.  **They're just two separate 32 or 64-bit data-storage spaces that software can use however they want.**

The natural categories to break them up are based on software / calling conventions:

- stack pointer
- call-preserved registers (function calls don't modify them, or conversely if you want to use one in a function you have to save/restore it)
- call-clobbered registers (function calls must be assumed to step on them, and conversely can be used without saving/restoring)
- the zero register.

Also arg-passing vs. return-value registers.

Comment: Now everything makes sense. Thank you! @Peter_Cordes